# Python Virtual Serial Ports On Windows

Tags: windows-7, serial-port, python-3.7, virtual-serial-port

I've got a windows 7 machine with numerous physical serial ports going into it and I would like the information coming into the machine to be read by multiple pieces of software at the same time. My first idea was a physical serial port splitter, however, this isn't viable as it may not have enough power to be split even once let alone multiple times.

So the next idea is to open a physical serial port on the computer and read everything coming through and then send that data to one or more virtual serial ports and then those virtual serial ports can be opened by individual pieces of software. After some research, I found a few pretty basic solutions which got my hopes up but they require "pty" which upon further research and a few "ModuleNotFound" errors I discovered this is for Mac Os only.

Is there any pty equivalent for windows or really anything that will make this possible? And if not is there something that is viable on Java or C++?

Comment: If you can do it on MacOS, can't you do it on Linux on many low-cost board computers? Is there a need for Windows 7?

Comment: I cannot use MacOs or Linux because the software I want the serial ports to interact with isn't compatible with either of those options.

Comment: Then it would be better to add more details about your ideal system configuration, examples of ideas/products that you have considered but were not able to adopt, and details of their problems. The content of your question seems too abstract to get an answer or advice.

Comment: My ideal system configuration is Windows 7, the products I have considered are any sort of python module and I have been unable to find one compatible with any form of windows. It's hard to narrow this question down, I want to be able to read serial port data (possible with pyserial) and send it down multiple virtual serial ports so that various other pieces of software can read the data instead of just one as serial ports can only be opened by one software at a time.

Comment: That's a repeat of the question, not a detail. It is better to add to the question what kind of devices (vendor, model number) are connected, what protocols are used, what are the communication conditions, communication frequency and data volume.